# Normalize a nested json file in Python

Tags: python, json, json-normalize

Suppose a list of objects: one, two, three,...

Every object is composed of name, foo1, and foo2 fields.

```
[{
    'name':'one',
    'foo2':{ 
        'id':'1.1',
        'id':'1.2'
    },
    'foo1':[
        {
            'foo2':{
                'id':'1.1',
                'name':'one.one'
            }
        }, 
        {
            'foo2':{
                'id':'1.2',
                'name':'one.two'
            }
        }
    ]
}]
```

If the object is normalize using:

```
obj_row_normalize = pd.json_normalize( object_row,
                                  record_path =['foo2'],
                                   meta=['name'],
                                   record_prefix='num_',
               )
```

The result is:

```
id  num_name  
1.1      one   
1.2      one
```

Given that, how can foo1.foo2.name be added to each resulting row as below:

```
id  num_name   name
1.1      one   one.one
1.2      one   one.two
```

Comment: `{'id': '1.1, 'id': '1.2'}` seems odd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the record path to `foo1`:

```py
pd.json_normalize(recs, record_path=['foo1'], meta='name')
  foo2.id foo2.name name
0     1.1   one.one  one
1     1.2   one.two  one
```